How to pass systemInstruction to firebase Genkit
export const processDocuemntFlow = defineFlow(
    {

        name: 'processDocuemntFlow',
        inputSchema: z.string(),
        outputSchema: noteSchema,
    },
   
    async (docuemntUrl) => {
        const llmResponse = await generate({

            model: gemini15FlashPreview,
            prompt: [{ text: `prompt` },
            ], output: { format: "json", schema: noteSchema },
            config: {
                temperature: 1,
            },

        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(llmResponse));

        return llmResponse.output();
    }
);

How to pass  systemInstruction: {
parts: [{"text": ..}]
}, to the vertex  model using genkit
Is there any way to pass systemInstruction Gen kit Nodejs SDK

Yes, definitely. Simply provide a message with role=system and Genkit will take care of the rest. The place to prepend messages like this to the prompt is the history field. For example:
import { generate } from '@genkit-ai/ai';
import { gemini15Flash } from '@genkit-ai/googleai';
import { MessageData } from "@genkit-ai/ai/model";

let history: MessageData[] = [
  { role: 'system', content: [{ text: 'Obey my instructions.' }] },
];

let response = await generate({
  model: gemini15Flash,
  prompt: [{ text: `prompt` },
  history,
});```

